# RecyclerView Search FIlter results are below the Toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, search, android-recyclerview

This might be a stupid question that I've tried very hard to find the answer with no success. I have a fragment that contains a recyclerView. The fragment is in the mainActivity which contains my custom toolbar and a bottonNavigationMenu. I've also made a search filter view for the recyclerView that works. The problem is this:
When I hit on the search for the recyclerView the first 2 results are below the Toolbar, thus not visible to the user. I had this problem with recyclerView (even when not using the search filter) and fixed it using the margins. But I don't know how to fix this one, so if you could help me out I'd really appreciate it.

Note: the search filter works just fine, I used prints to test it, it's just that the 2 first results are below the toolbar and not visible.

Fragment's xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chatsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.674"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

RecyclerViewItem xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FF5733"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewChatCard"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/joinButtonChatCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:text="@string/join"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:cornerRadius="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

SearchFilter's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/searchFilterChats"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        />
    
</menu>
```

MainActivity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/appToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:titleMarginStart="80dp"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white"/>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="673dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The search results I get->  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmyIk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the constraint that have `FragmentContainerView` and `BottomNavigationView` .

Here's convenient that `BottomNavigationView`  have a fixed size.

And `FragmentContainerView` set limit to top with `@+id/appBarLayout2` and limit to bottom with `@+id/bottomNavigationView`.

The `MainActivity xml` would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/appToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:titleMarginStart="80dp"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!--this was modified-->
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout2"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

    <!--this was modified-->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```